# Why is data-bs-interval="false" no longer working in bootstrap 5.2.3 in year 2023?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please look at the following example:

```css
#carouselExampleControls {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" data-bs-interval="false" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      111
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      222
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="false">
      333
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In older SO posts it was suggested that `data-bs-interval="false"` will stop automatic running of the bootstrap slider, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore, why is that?

Answer (score 5):

Remove `data-bs-ride="carousel"` from your

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" data-bs-interval="false" class="carousel slide" >
```

The `data-bs-ride="carousel"` attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load.
If you delete it, you will have to interact with it yourself, so you need to press the buttons

Comment: this is the correct answer, @user31782 you should make it resolved

Comment: @remi Sorry, I don't have the time to read the bootstrap docs again. There must have been a reason, I didn't accept this answer originally.